# React Native onSubmitEditing in a TextInput without keyboard

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I'm trying to use a barcode reader in my app so I can fill a TextInput within using software keyboard.

The idea is to use something like this:

```
<TextInput
    autoFocus={true}
    onFocus={Keyboard.dismiss}
    multiline={false}
    onSubmitEditing={() => this.submitFunction()}
/>
```

It partialy works as I want, I can read the code and It's shown properly but `onSubmitEditing` is not called.

Does anyone knows how to hide keyboard on a `TextView` but mantain the focus so `onSubmitEditing` is called?

If keyboard isn't dismissed `onSubmitEditing` run as spected.

Comment: It's not normal that Android's Keyboard isn't dismissed when you have a barcode reader connected. Did you test it in a phone?

Comment: Now we can hide the keyboard without losing focus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639041/react-native-textinput-with-focus-but-without-keyboard-showing